# Duplicate on 2 fields

Tags: laravel

I looking a way to avoid the duplicates in Laravel. For example, I have a table with 2 fields which are `name` and `firstname`.

How to manage the duplicates on the Controller? I am newbie...

[image]

Here is my function store().

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:25',
                'firstname' => 'required|string|max:25'

        ]);

        $exists = Auteur::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstName', $request->get('firstName'))->count();

        if (!$exists){
            Auteur::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('auteurs.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
        }


    }
```

I thank you for your help and your explanations.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent duplicates from being created?

Comment: @d3jn: Yes, I don't know how to do ??

Comment: Use built-in validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were one field, you could use validation, or make that field unique and that would take care of it with a little error handling.  However, with two fields to have to check against, it might be easiest to check if the element is already in the database and deduplicate from there.  So in the `store()` method:

```
$exists = Auteur::where('name', $req->get('name'))->where('firstname', $req->get('firstname')->count();

if (!$exists){
    // create the new model, now that we know there is no duplicate in the database
    Auteur::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, do you have a small example because I am very beginner. I don't  understand the condition with model.

Comment: The first line checks the database to see if there is a model already in existence with the exact firstname and name.  If there is, `count()` will be true.  If there are no matches with the exact same name, `count()` will be zero and thus false.  Since the value of `count()` is going into the `$exists` variable, if it is false, we are safe to create the new model, since there are no others with the exact same name currently within the database.  I'll edit to include the create code

Comment: thank you for your valuable explanations. I edited my first message by adding your code. The duplicate system does not work yet ... Have I missed a step?

Comment: Check your column names - I had `firstName` - maybe it is `firstname`? Also, your return statement is sending back success and save - are these what you are trying to send?  You may wish to move your return statement outside the if-check so that something always returns.  What exactly is not working?  What is the error message?

Comment: Yeeeeeessssss !!! Indeed, it was the variable `firstName` the problem... Thank thank you a lot for your help and explanation. I am happy, my problem is solve now. ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add unique in your validation rule. If you would like to check unique validation each field separately.

```
$request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|unique:auteurs,name|string|max:25',
                'firstname' => 'required|unique:auteurs,firstname|string|max:25'

        ]);

Here I hope the table name is `auteurs`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it must block the same name and firstname for an id.